# How to prevent SharePoint online from sending invitation emails when a workflow alters item permission?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, notifications

In a document library, item permissions are set with a workflow regarding metadata in custom columns.
Every time an item changes and the workflow grants permission to a specific group, every group member receives an invitation email.

How to prevent SharePoint online from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOB method. The invitation email is defined in the AclInv.aspx. But we are not able to change the application pages in SharePoint Online.

Comment: That's bad, SharePoint online looks to me like an unfinished product, especially the 'new experience'